# The following _TypeError was thrown building MessageBubble(dirty): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
The relevant error-causing widget was
MessageBubble

i am expecting to open my chat screen but this happened.
[image: chat screen]

Comment: Well, one of your strings was null. Without any code, there is nothing more we can do for you. You need to add more details (like a stacktrace and code) or find the error on your own.